# how to override specific jre jars with third party jars in ant build

Tags: ant

I am using Ant 1.7.1 to build our application in eclipse. My application is going to be deployed on WAS 6.1. As I am using sun.security.* package classes and sub-packages in my code (I know it is not recommended to use this package, but have no other option).

When I deployed the ear in WAS, I got a ClassDefNotFoundError for sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId class. I found that this class is not present in the desired package in IBM Jre ( this is the kind of reason why it is not recommended to use sun. packages).

I had to put IBM jars in my development classpath and made eclipse use these jars instead of my local JRE jars by putting the IBM jars ahead of the JRE jars in the eclipse - order and export. This is working fine.

Now, my question is, how to do the same ordering of the jars in ANT. I know how to specify the order of jars in ANT classpath. But how do I put the IBM jars ahead of JRE jars in ANT?

I tried setting the IBM jars in boot classpath. But doing that, ANT is not able to find java.lang because, the java classpath is out of boot classpath now.

```
              <javac  source="1.5"
            target="1.5"
            bootclasspathref="project.class.path"
            destdir = "${build.classes.dir}"
            srcdir = "${work.dir}/src" 
            debug="true"
            encoding="UTF-8"
    >
    <classpath path="${java.library.path}"/>

    </javac>
```

Please advise how to get this done.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for this. I made the following change to 'javac' task:

```
      <javac  source="1.5"
              target="1.5"
              destdir = "${build.classes.dir}"
              srcdir = "${work.dir}/src" 
              debug="true"
              encoding="UTF-8"
      >
       **<compilerarg value="-Xbootclasspath/p:${toString:project.class.path}"/>**
     </javac>
```

Ant it worked!!